# Simplifying a mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following query but it is taking 12 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT t.*,
       tt.*
FROM   wp_terms AS t
       INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
               ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy IN ( 'category' )
ORDER  BY t.name ASC
```

Is their any way to simplify the query to achieve the same result with less of a delay.

Comment: How much data is there in `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy`? Are the tables indexed?

Comment: In order of priority: 1. provide and index on (tt.term_id,tt.category). 2. Provide an index on t.name. 3. Name the columns you actually want returned. Incidentally, only by convention, we tend to join the table without the WHERE condition on to the table with the WHERE condition - not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better performance with 
`SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' ORDER BY t.name ASC`

By removing the `IN`; but other than that - your bottleneck is going to be the `JOIN`.  Make sure your tables are properly indexed and if they're just too big... well, it'll take time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an index on term_id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add indexes and use '=' instead of 'IN'

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all data from both tables or are you selecting t.* and tt.* because its quicker to code?

Can you pair down what you are selecting from the statement.

Also can you add a group by to the statement. This could reduce your rowcount on return and increase performance.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `IN` unless you have to.

```
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category'
```

Comment: I'd like to see a proof how this changes the query execution time in any way.

Comment: I found this while looking around: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30330 But that would almost imply the opposite...  Edit: it should be noted that this is also a bug from a very old version.

Comment: Or the questioner can try it and see.